# Show user page only if displayed (and not current) user has a specific role

Tags: users

On my site, anonymous users can access user information with this type of url: /user/25

It works fine, I created a template for this branch: user–full-html-twig.

However, I would like this type of url to be accessible only if the displayed user (and not the current user) has a specific role. For example, in this case the user with ID 25 has a role “member” for example. /user/25 will therefore display the template with the user information.

On the other hand, if you access /user/1 (admin role), access would be denied. How to proceed ?

For nodes, I use [rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) which is very powerful. Even though this module has a user module, it does not allow me to do what I want. It lacks the ability to redirect or deny access for a specific role (like for content types).

To sum up, I would like to show the profiles of users who have a specific role and redirect or disallow access to profile pages for admin roles.

A partial solution to at least hide information for admins is to make this type of condition in the twig:

```
{% if 'member' in user.getroles(TRUE)  %}

   {# user content #}

{% else %}

    <p>access denied</p>

{% endif %}
```

It's not elegant but at least hides unwanted profiles. I was wondering if I have to go through permissions or if a module can do what I want.

Comment: Remove 'access user profiles' permission for anonymous users on your site.

Comment: @Jaypan I want user profiles to be accessible to anonymous users. but I want them not to access the profile of certain roles, in particular administrator or content_editor.

Comment: `/user/25` is accessible to anonymous users but not `/user/1`

Comment: I would just create a custom access plugin for this, not twig.